# PHP and Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I easily implement queries in Zend framework?

Comment: Query what? Web service, database (mssql,mysql,sqlite,...)?

Comment: using a MVC framework to query a database is like using rocket launcher to kill a cockroach.  too much.  unless your database query is part of a MUCH larger project.  but it doesn't sound like that's the case.  straight php would be much easier to implement IMHO

Comment: After setting up the skeleton element follow the steps. http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/first-module.html

Answer (score 5):

Check this document:

[Zend Framework Database Quick Start](http://devzone.zend.com/content/zendcon_07_slides/Karwin_Bill_ZF-Db-ZendCon-20071009.pdf) *(PDF)*

Comment: This link doesn't work no more. Check the official manual page:
[http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html]

Answer (score 1):

You can use doctrine2
[Doctrine project](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).
There is a module compatibile with ZF3
[DoctrineModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule).
You can use QueryBuilder that brings creation of query to object manipulation.

Comment: I highly recommend Doctrine as well.  It has a high learning curve, but once you master it, you'll cut your DB work by 75%.  It also integrates with most popular frameworks and standard PHP, so you won't have to relearn it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Zend Db Adapter object like so:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE bug_id = ?';

$result = $db->fetchAll($sql, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend_Db and just create a $db Object using Zend_Db Factory Method, and then create SQL Statements using Zend_Db_Select Class and pass the $select SQL Statement to the fetch* (fetchRow, fetchAll...) Methods.

Answer (score 0):

1.Config:

config/autoload/dbAdapter.local.php

```
<?php
return array(
   'db' => array(
        'driver'   => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'      => 'mysql:dbname=name;host=localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',    
   ),
   'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

2. Implementation:

> ```
> public function testAction()
> {
>   $username = 'user';
>
>
>   $sql       = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = ?";
>   $statement = $this->getDbAdapter()->createStatement($sql, array($username));
>   $result   = $statement->execute()->current();
> }
>
>
>
> protected function getDbAdapter()
> {
>     if($this->dbAdapter == null) {
>         $this->dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
>     }
>
>     return $this->dbAdapter;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Zend framework has abstract_factories ,it allows us to handle multiple DB queries :

Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory

1. Need to set Service Manager :

   'service_manager' => array( 
       'abstract_factories' => array(
           'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
       ),
   ),
2. Configure adapters in config/autoload/local.php

   db' => array(
       'adapters' => array(

   ```
       'database1' => array(
          'driver'         => 'Pdo',
          'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=userDB;host=localhost',
          'driver_options'  => array(
               PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
           ),
       ),

       etc...
   ),
   ```

   ),
3. Configure adapters in config/autoload/global.php

   ```
   return array(
   'db' => array(
       'adapters' => array(
           'database1' => array(
           'username' => 'root',
           'password' => '',
           ),
       ),    
   ),
   ```

   );
4. Call adapters

   $dbmanager->get('database1');
5. Use in Model

   ```
   use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
   use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

   class UserTable extends AbstractTableGateway
   {
       protected $table ='user';

   public function __invoke(Adapter $adapter)
   {
       $this->adapter = $adapter;
       $this->initialize();
   }

   public function fetchAll()
   {
       $resultSet = $this->select();
       return $resultSet->toArray();
   }
   ```

   }